# Angular OnPush: an updated Input string won't update the template

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template, angular-changedetection

There is a parent component with default `changeDetection` and two child components with `onPush` change detection strategy. While the input variable is being updated, the template will not update. I can't used async pipes in the `ChildBComponent` as it is a global UI component for the project and refactoring is not an option. How do I go about this?

**parent.ts**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'parent',
   template: `
   <div>
     <child-a>
        <child-b [label]="firstLabel"></child-b>
        <child-b [label]="secondLabel"></child-b>
        <child-b label="Just a plain label"></child-b>
     </child-a>
   </div>`
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

   public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.httpService.loadData()
        .subscribe(data => {
           this.someValue = 1;
           this.otherValue = 2;
        });
   }

   // getters to explicitly trigger change detection
   public get firstLabel(): string {
     return `Something ${ this.someValue || '?'}`;
   }

   public get secondLabel(): string {
     return `Different ${ this.otherValue || '?'}`;
   }
}
```

**child-a.ts**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'child-a',
   template: `
      <div>Layout wrapper</div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>`,
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildBComponent implements AfterContentInit {
}
```

**child-b.ts**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'child-b',
   template: '<div>{{ label }}</div>',
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildBComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
   @Input public label: string;
}
```

I tried converting `@Input` into getter/setter - to no avail. When debugging, the changes are coming through, but the template will only update if I click on the component itself. Throwing in a `markForCheck()` didn't help either.

And idea is helpful.

Edit: Added [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bltcxp?file=src/app/app.component.html). Please use a wide preview to see the issue; miraculously it works properly when mobile view elements are shown.

Comment: Have you tried marking the parent for check in `loadData.subscribe`?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on an online IDE like [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: @Siddhant added the link to Stackblitz

Comment: @pop Thanks for the Stackblitz. I have added an answer trying to explain the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with Change Detection, and the label values are correctly reflected in html. The change in `countA` and `countB` values do get reflected in HTML, it's just the CSS that gives the impression as if the html is not updated.

In `fieldtabs.component.html` you have logic to display tabs via `<ul>` and you also have `<ng-content>`.

The problem is when the device has max width of `767.98px`, the `<ul *ngIf="!vertical" class="fieldtabs--tabs-container">` element is not shown as a result of below CSS:

```css
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .fieldtabs--tabs-container {
      display:none
  }
}
```

whereas the `<fieldtab>` i.e the Content Children are only visible when device max width is `767.98px`. Below is the CSS responsible for the same:

```css
.fieldtabs-l {
  display: none
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .fieldtabs-l {
      display:flex;
      align-items: center
  }
}
```

The fieldtab template html responsible for displaying `label` has the above class:

```html
<div *ngIf="!invisible" class="fieldtabs-l fieldtab--accord"
```

So when device max width is 767.98px:

- The `{{ label }}` interpolation present within your OnPush Content child `fieldtab` template is visible
- The `{{ tab.label }}` interpolation present within your OnPush `fieldtabs` template is not visible

When width is greater than 767.98px, the opposite happens i.e `{{ tab.label}}` is what you see on the screen, which doesn't get updated as the `tabs` are being constructed within `ngAfterContentInit` and the method won't be called again when `countA` and `countB` get assigned new values.

Comment: Correct. I guess, I‘d need to push changes to Fieldtabs.Component for it to reflect the label state correctly. Thx!